# Trouble with inserting notes into a JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a `JTree` which is constructed with the following method:
(The `BKMNode` class extends `DefaultMutableTreeNode`, and the`DataNode` simply holds the data)

```
 void populateTree(BKMNode parent) {
    for (DataNode node : nodes) {
        BKMNode treeNode = new BKMNode(node.name,node.fullName,null);
        // check if this node was already added before
        if (! existingNodes.contains(ip + "." + node.fullName)) {
            existingNodes.add(ip + "." + node.fullName);
            DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel)tree.getModel();
            model.insertNodeInto(treeNode, parent, parent.getChildCount());
            System.out.println("adding " + ip + "." + node.fullName);
        }
        node.populateTree(treeNode);
    }
```

`// some more non-relevant code...`

When the tree is created at the application startup, everything is fine.
But once in a while my application adds nodes to the tree using the same method.
When the application attempts to add a new node to the tree in does print the text, but nothing changes on the `GUI`.
I tried calling `JTree.invalidate()`, `validate()`, `repaint()`, `reload()` but nothing seems to help.

The `populateTree` method is always called from the `EDT`.

Does anyone know what's the problems here?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an SSCCE (http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: Also, where are you actually modifying a JTree?  It looks like you create a new DefaultTreeModel every time you insert a node?  Shouldn't you be clearing out an existing DefaultTreeModel and adding nodes to it?

Comment: I don't create a new model, I acquire a reference to it using the reference to the tree object itself, and I modify the JTree by invoking the insertNodeInto on its model

Comment: You're right, I read that wrong.  Try adding your own TreeListener to the tree model.  That way you can isolate whether the problem is 1) The TreeModel simply isn't adding the node (maybe it can't find the parent or something) or 2) Swing simply isn't updating the tree's display to match the new model.

Comment: Like, Andrew said an SSCCE would be nice, as the code you posted appears fine as it is.  There must be another issue.  Half the time you find the problem just developing the SSCCE.

Comment: ok I added a treeListener that prints the name of the node when it is expanded, and it does print the new nodes- just not shows them!

Comment: Where in the code do you call invalidate()?

Comment: I tried and it didn't work, so i removed it. Trust me, I tried using every invalidate, validate, repaint, reload method

Answer (score 3):

> Trust me, I tried using every invalidate, validate, repaint, reload method

Sorry, I don't trust you, people make silly mistakes all the time. That is why we need a SSCCE to see exactly what your are doing. Having said that, there is no reason to invoke any of those methods. invalidate(), validate() are used when you add/remove components from a Container, which you have not done. When you update a model, the model is responsible for notifying the view so the view can repaint itself.

> but nothing changes on the GUI

What do you expect to change?

Inserting a node inserts a node into the model. If the parent node is expanded, then yes you should see the inserted node. However if the parent node is collapsed you will not see a change.

If you want to see the node after you insert it then you can use the tree.expandPath(...) method.

The basic code you posted works fine for me when I insert a default node containing a String value. Maybe the problem is your custom node? So the first thing you need to do is create a SSCCE that works with the default node. Once that works you replace the default node with your custom node. If it works, great. If not you know the problem is your custom node.

Based on the code provided it should work, so you need to give us more to work with.

Comment: Edit: I built a SSCCE, and even used the same cell renderer and everything works perfectly... :/

Comment: So now you need to determine what is different between the SSCCE and your real application. Maybe you have two references to the tree and/or model. One is a class variable and one is a local variable. So you end up updating a reference that is not visible on the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I added some breakpoints at the "nodesWereInserted" method in the DefaultTreeModel's source and run the application with a debugger. It showed that the new nodes were added with a null parent! Further investigation showed the problem - the node.populateTree(treeNode); line added the new node without it being connected its indended parent.
This is the new (working) code. Thanks a lot for the help.

```
    void populateTree(BKMNode parent) {
    for (DataNode node : nodes) {
        BKMNode treeNode = new BKMNode(node.name,node.fullName,null);
        // check if this node was already added before
        if (! existingNodes.contains(ip + "." + node.fullName)) {
            existingNodes.add(ip + "." + node.fullName);
            DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel)tree.getModel();
            model.insertNodeInto(treeNode, parent, parent.getChildCount());
            node.bkmNode = treeNode;
            node.populateTree(treeNode);
        } else {
            node.populateTree(node.bkmNode);
        }
    } // for
```